# Problems with converting json string to dataset c#?

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to use the JSON.Net library for converting a json string to a dataset. But I keep getting the error 'Additional text found in JSON string after finishing deserializing object.' What could I be doing wrong ?

JSON string -

```
[
   {
      "title":"'Grenfell changes everything': Shadow of high-rise fire looms across UK",
      "pubDate":"2017-06-24 10:55:47",
      "link":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/24/europe/london-fire-grenfell-tower/index.html",
      "guid":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/24/europe/london-fire-grenfell-tower/index.html",
      "author":"",
      "thumbnail":"",
      "description":"Ten days after an inferno swept through Grenfell Tower in west London, leaving the apartment block a blackened shell and claiming the lives of at least 79 people, a shadow hangs over Britain.",
      "content":"Ten days after an inferno swept through Grenfell Tower in west London, leaving the apartment block a blackened shell and claiming the lives of at least 79 people, a shadow hangs over Britain.",
      "enclosure":{
         "link":"http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/170621150157-01-london-protests-0621-super-169.jpg"
      },
      "categories":[

      ]
   },
   {
      "title":"Saudis: Attack foiled on Grand Mosque in Mecca",
      "pubDate":"2017-06-24 10:27:00",
      "link":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/23/middleeast/grand-mosque-attack-foiled/index.html",
      "guid":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/23/middleeast/grand-mosque-attack-foiled/index.html",
      "author":"",
      "thumbnail":"",
      "description":"Saudi security forces on Friday prevented an imminent attack on the Grand Mosque in Mecca, the country's Interior Ministry said on state-run TV.",
      "content":"Saudi security forces on Friday prevented an imminent attack on the Grand Mosque in Mecca, the country's Interior Ministry said on state-run TV.",
      "enclosure":{
         "link":"http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/170624130705-mecca-plot-foiled-super-169.jpg"
      },
      "categories":[

      ]
   },
   {
      "title":"Qatar handed stern list of 13 demands by Arab states",
      "pubDate":"2017-06-24 09:24:20",
      "link":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/23/middleeast/gulf-nations-qatar-demands/index.html",
      "guid":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/23/middleeast/gulf-nations-qatar-demands/index.html",
      "author":"",
      "thumbnail":"",
      "description":"Four Arab states that have isolated Qatar have handed the country a list of 13 demands, including some that are likely to infuriate Doha and exacerbate the region's worst crisis in decades.",
      "content":"Four Arab states that have isolated Qatar have handed the country a list of 13 demands, including some that are likely to infuriate Doha and exacerbate the region's worst crisis in decades.",
      "enclosure":{
         "link":"http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/160619161356-al-jazeera-hq-qatar-super-169.jpg"
      },
      "categories":[

      ]
   },
   {
      "title":"Turkey to stop teaching evolution in high schools",
      "pubDate":"2017-06-24 06:21:59",
      "link":"http://www.cnn.com/collections/intl-turkey-evolution-theory/",
      "guid":"http://www.cnn.com/collections/intl-turkey-evolution-theory/",
      "author":"",
      "thumbnail":"",
      "description":"",
      "content":"",
      "enclosure":{
         "link":"http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/170613133545-01-recep-tayyip-erdogan-0613-super-169.jpg"
      },
      "categories":[

      ]
   },
   {
      "title":"China: More than 100 feared buried in landslide",
      "pubDate":"2017-06-24 10:03:43",
      "link":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/23/china/china-landslide/index.html",
      "guid":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/23/china/china-landslide/index.html",
      "author":"",
      "thumbnail":"",
      "description":"A landslide in southwest China's Sichuan province buried more than 100 people, the Chinese state-run broadcaster China Central Television (CCTV) reported Saturday.",
      "content":"A landslide in southwest China's Sichuan province buried more than 100 people, the Chinese state-run broadcaster China Central Television (CCTV) reported Saturday.",
      "enclosure":{
         "link":"http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/170624160125-xinmo-landslide-distance-super-169.jpg"
      },
      "categories":[

      ]
   },
   {
      "title":"Ex-Obama official: Handling of Russia 'is hardest thing to defend,' WaPo reports",
      "pubDate":"2017-06-23 17:47:54",
      "link":"http://www.cnn.com/collections/intl-wapo-former-obama-official/",
      "guid":"http://www.cnn.com/collections/intl-wapo-former-obama-official/",
      "author":"",
      "thumbnail":"",
      "description":"",
      "content":"",
      "enclosure":{
         "link":"http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/170615132528-01-vladimir-putin-0615-super-169.jpg"
      },
      "categories":[

      ]
   },
   {
      "title":"White House banned cameras, so CNN sent a sketch artist",
      "pubDate":"2017-06-24 01:42:28",
      "link":"http://money.cnn.com/2017/06/23/media/white-house-press-briefing-sketch-artist/index.html",
      "guid":"http://money.cnn.com/2017/06/23/media/white-house-press-briefing-sketch-artist/index.html",
      "author":"",
      "thumbnail":"",
      "description":"",
      "content":"",
      "enclosure":{
         "link":"http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/170623172331-wh-briefing-colored-sketches-1-super-169.jpg"
      },
      "categories":[

      ]
   },
   {
      "title":"Prosecutors ask to reinstate Hernandez's murder conviction",
      "pubDate":"2017-06-23 21:37:38",
      "link":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/23/us/aaron-hernandez-appeal-conviction/index.html",
      "guid":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/23/us/aaron-hernandez-appeal-conviction/index.html",
      "author":"",
      "thumbnail":"",
      "description":"Bristol County prosecutors officially asked to reinstate Aaron Hernandez's murder conviction on Friday, arguing in court documents that the former NFL player's suicide should not lead to dismissal of the guilty verdict.",
      "content":"Bristol County prosecutors officially asked to reinstate Aaron Hernandez's murder conviction on Friday, arguing in court documents that the former NFL player's suicide should not lead to dismissal of the guilty verdict.",
      "enclosure":{
         "link":"http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/170420132012-01-aaron-hernandez-court-file-super-169.jpg"
      },
      "categories":[

      ]
   },
   {
      "title":"White House responds to Comey tape inquiry with Trump tweet",
      "pubDate":"2017-06-24 10:29:09",
      "link":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/23/politics/white-house-comey-tapes-trump-tweet/index.html",
      "guid":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/23/politics/white-house-comey-tapes-trump-tweet/index.html",
      "author":"",
      "thumbnail":"",
      "description":"The White House is letting President Donald Trump's tweet Thursday -- asserting that he had not taped former FBI Director James Comey -- stand as the President's official statement.",
      "content":"The White House is letting President Donald Trump's tweet Thursday -- asserting that he had not taped former FBI Director James Comey -- stand as the President's official statement.",
      "enclosure":{
         "link":"http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/170623093958-donald-trump-0622-super-169.jpg"
      },
      "categories":[

      ]
   },
   {
      "title":"Trump faces Putin in 2 weeks",
      "pubDate":"2017-06-23 19:41:29",
      "link":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/23/politics/trump-putin-meeting-g20/index.html",
      "guid":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/23/politics/trump-putin-meeting-g20/index.html",
      "author":"",
      "thumbnail":"",
      "description":"Inside the capacious Hamburg Messe conference hall next month, President Donald Trump will come face-to-face with the man whose shadow has darkened much of his presidency: Vladimir Putin.",
      "content":"Inside the capacious Hamburg Messe conference hall next month, President Donald Trump will come face-to-face with the man whose shadow has darkened much of his presidency: Vladimir Putin.",
      "enclosure":{
         "link":"http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/170407053321-02-trump-putin-split-0407-super-169.jpg"
      },
      "categories":[

      ]
   },
   {
      "title":"New Zealand's All Blacks overpower Lions in series opener",
      "pubDate":"2017-06-24 11:30:20",
      "link":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/24/sport/new-zealand-british-and-irish-lions-rugby-eden-park-auckland/index.html",
      "guid":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/24/sport/new-zealand-british-and-irish-lions-rugby-eden-park-auckland/index.html",
      "author":"",
      "thumbnail":"",
      "description":"For the touring British and Irish Lions, the early signs are ominous.",
      "content":"For the touring British and Irish Lions, the early signs are ominous.",
      "enclosure":{
         "link":"http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/170624095656-codie-taylor-super-169.jpg"
      },
      "categories":[

      ]
   },
   {
      "title":"Violent protests spread in India's Darjeeling tea lands",
      "pubDate":"2017-06-23 09:38:31",
      "link":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/23/asia/darjeeling-crisis-india/index.html",
      "guid":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/23/asia/darjeeling-crisis-india/index.html",
      "author":"",
      "thumbnail":"",
      "description":"The sleepy hills of India's northeast have erupted into violence, as calls for a separate state for the area's Nepali-speaking Gorkhas gain traction.",
      "content":"The sleepy hills of India's northeast have erupted into violence, as calls for a separate state for the area's Nepali-speaking Gorkhas gain traction.",
      "enclosure":{
         "link":"http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/170623102753-gorkha-protest-super-169.jpg"
      },
      "categories":[

      ]
   },
   {
      "title":"Air Force 'doomsday' planes damaged in tornado",
      "pubDate":"2017-06-23 22:09:54",
      "link":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/23/politics/air-force-planes-damaged-tornado/index.html",
      "guid":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/23/politics/air-force-planes-damaged-tornado/index.html",
      "author":"",
      "thumbnail":"",
      "description":"Ten US Air Force planes, including two E-4B \"doomsday\" aircraft, were damaged when a tornado hit near Offutt Air Force Base in Nebraska last week, the service told CNN on Friday.",
      "content":"Ten US Air Force planes, including two E-4B \"doomsday\" aircraft, were damaged when a tornado hit near Offutt Air Force Base in Nebraska last week, the service told CNN on Friday.",
      "enclosure":{
         "link":"http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/170623173900-e-4b-national-airborne-operations-center-super-169.jpg"
      },
      "categories":[

      ]
   },
   {
      "title":"South Korea's new presidential pooches, and why they matter",
      "pubDate":"2017-06-24 02:54:17",
      "link":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/23/opinions/south-korea-dogs-animal-welfare/index.html",
      "guid":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/23/opinions/south-korea-dogs-animal-welfare/index.html",
      "author":"",
      "thumbnail":"",
      "description":"When South Korea's new president Moon Jae-in took up residency in the Blue House last month, his choice of pets raised some eyebrows.",
      "content":"When South Korea's new president Moon Jae-in took up residency in the Blue House last month, his choice of pets raised some eyebrows.",
      "enclosure":{
         "link":"http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/170606205829-s-korea-dog-breeders-super-169.jpg"
      },
      "categories":[

      ]
   },
   {
      "title":"Al Jazeera: What you need to know",
      "pubDate":"2017-06-23 16:01:18",
      "link":"http://www.cnn.com/videos/cnnmoney/2017/06/23/al-jazeera-explainer-mxb-lon-orig.cnnmoney",
      "guid":"http://www.cnn.com/videos/cnnmoney/2017/06/23/al-jazeera-explainer-mxb-lon-orig.cnnmoney",
      "author":"",
      "thumbnail":"",
      "description":"CNN's Frederik Pleitgen takes a look at the controversies surrounding this global news network based in Qatar.",
      "content":"CNN's Frederik Pleitgen takes a look at the controversies surrounding this global news network based in Qatar.",
      "enclosure":{
         "link":"http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/170623165833-al-jazeera-1-super-169.jpg"
      },
      "categories":[

      ]
   },
   {
      "title":"The world will solve its own problems -- with or without Trump",
      "pubDate":"2017-06-23 11:36:51",
      "link":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/23/opinions/us-global-leadership-robertson/index.html",
      "guid":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/23/opinions/us-global-leadership-robertson/index.html",
      "author":"",
      "thumbnail":"",
      "description":"It's been a blistering week in London, with little shade from the sun or the news.",
      "content":"It's been a blistering week in London, with little shade from the sun or the news.",
      "enclosure":{
         "link":"http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/170602164707-trump-world-leaders-super-169.jpg"
      },
      "categories":[

      ]
   },
   {
      "title":"US releases dramatic photos of 'unsafe' Russian jet intercept",
      "pubDate":"2017-06-23 18:16:02",
      "link":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/23/politics/russian-jet-intercepts-us-aircraft-photos/index.html",
      "guid":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/23/politics/russian-jet-intercepts-us-aircraft-photos/index.html",
      "author":"",
      "thumbnail":"",
      "description":"US European Command released dramatic photos on Thursday that show the moment a Russian Su-27 fighter jet flew within five feet of a US Air Force RC-135 reconnaissance aircraft over the Baltic Sea -- an encounter US officials assessed to be \"unsafe.\"",
      "content":"US European Command released dramatic photos on Thursday that show the moment a Russian Su-27 fighter jet flew within five feet of a US Air Force RC-135 reconnaissance aircraft over the Baltic Sea -- an encounter US officials assessed to be \"unsafe.\"",
      "enclosure":{
         "link":"http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/170623121807-russian-unsafe-intercept-01-super-169.jpg"
      },
      "categories":[

      ]
   },
   {
      "title":"May's Brexit divorce deal branded 'not sufficient'",
      "pubDate":"2017-06-23 13:40:08",
      "link":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/23/europe/eu-nationals-brexit-may/index.html",
      "guid":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/23/europe/eu-nationals-brexit-may/index.html",
      "author":"",
      "thumbnail":"",
      "description":"British Prime Minister Theresa May's plans to secure the rights of EU nationals after Brexit have been criticized as \"not sufficient,\" by the head of the European Commission.",
      "content":"British Prime Minister Theresa May's plans to secure the rights of EU nationals after Brexit have been criticized as \"not sufficient,\" by the head of the European Commission.",
      "enclosure":{
         "link":"http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/170623094855-04-theresa-may-brussels-0623-super-169.jpg"
      },
      "categories":[

      ]
   },
   {
      "title":"No break for Britain: 5 tragedies in 3 months",
      "pubDate":"",
      "link":"http://cnn.it/2rLuYi4",
      "guid":"http://cnn.it/2rLuYi4",
      "author":"",
      "thumbnail":"",
      "description":"",
      "content":"",
      "enclosure":{
         "link":"http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/170623162903-01-uk-tragedies-cnnphotos-super-169.jpg"
      },
      "categories":[

      ]
   },
   {
      "title":"Splash 'dancing' at the Dallas Zoo with Zola the gorilla",
      "pubDate":"2017-06-24 11:51:21",
      "link":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/24/us/dallas-zoo-dancing-gorilla-trnd/index.html",
      "guid":"http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/24/us/dallas-zoo-dancing-gorilla-trnd/index.html",
      "author":"",
      "thumbnail":"",
      "description":"There seems to be a lot more going on behind the scenes at the Dallas Zoo -- including some splashy dance moves by Zola the gorilla.",
      "content":"There seems to be a lot more going on behind the scenes at the Dallas Zoo -- including some splashy dance moves by Zola the gorilla.",
      "enclosure":{
         "link":"http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/170624051705-dallas-zoo-gorilla-zola-splash-pool-sot-nr-00002328-super-169.jpg"
      },
      "categories":[

      ]
   }]
```

This is what I tried

```
[WebMethod]
    public string RSSfeeddata(string info) {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(
    WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        var outObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(info);
        DataSet myDataSet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(info);     
        return info;
    }
```

Comment: I cannot see any problem in your JSON but I noticed something: the first title is `'Grenfell changes everything': Shadow of high-rise fire looms across UK` this value is kind of a JSON format and maybe `JsonConvert ` is trying to convert this also

Comment: @ElmerDantas I just ran the same json through JsonConvert on my PC and that worked without issues.

Comment: It's a quoted string, @ElmerDantas

Comment: @EdPlunkett I know it is...is a valid json, but as I said, json converter is trying to convert this piece inside of the json as a json also (just wondering). The best you can do is create a object with the properties you want and then use the object to deserialize ;)

Comment: @ElmerDantas It is, or you're just wondering if it is? Can you show me an example of this particular serializer demonstrating that bug?

Comment: I'm just wondering if it is...see the answer below, that will probably help you. Because is the one thing I would say that is missing

Comment: @ElmerDantas I'm not OP. There is no such bug in the Newtonsoft JSON parser. You could have easily tested that for yourself, if you weren't just here to waste OP's time on nonsense stories.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can deserialze that Json into a dataset is if you had serialized it from a dataset in the first place. Instead, you can create a class that works with the Json you have. To do that, copy the Json into your clipboard, create a new .json file in Visual Studio, click on the Edit menu, go to paste special, then Paste JSON as classes. For me it generated...

```
public class Class1
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string pubDate { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
    public string guid { get; set; }
    public string author { get; set; }
    public string thumbnail { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string content { get; set; }
    public Enclosure enclosure { get; set; }
    public object[] categories { get; set; }
}

public class Enclosure
{
    public string link { get; set; }
}
```

You then read the json into an `IEnumerable<Class1>` (I didn't rename the class) as follows

```
var text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("json1.json");

var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Class1>>(text);
```

You can then use that IEnumerable in place of the dataset.